# Use of Dropdown button in React

Tags: reactjs, web, drop-down-menu

I want to use the react Dropdownbutton to build a list, but i receive the following error :

> TypeError: react_dropdown__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.Dropdown is undefined

Here is my code :

```
render() {
return (
  <div className="Upload">
    {this.renderNotes()}
    <Dropdown>
      <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
        Dropdown Button
      </Dropdown.Toggle>

      <Dropdown.Menu>
        <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">Action</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">Another action</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">Something else</Dropdown.Item>
      </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
  </div>

);
```

And the import :

```
import { Dropdown } from "react-dropdown";
```

I have install it using the command : `npm install react-dropdown --save`

EDIT : I had to use `import Dropdown from "react-dropdown";`
But now the website compiles, but the list does not display...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are trying to import a [**named export**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Using_named_exports). However `react-dropdown` exports that module as the [**default**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Using_the_default_export). import it like so

```
import Dropdown from 'react-dropdown'
```

also, make sure you import the styles for this component

```
import 'react-dropdown/style.css'
```

Comment: I dont see an update, also probably best to ask a question for specific issues so questions dont get mixed up

Comment: Is the dropdown rendering?

Comment: Hard to debug what your webpage is or isn't showing, can you post a jsfiddle or something replicating the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194559/discussion-between-cocool97-and-john-ruddell).